# How do I not get CSS files to carry over in React?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm currently trying to set up a multipage React project, but when I create a new page, it applies every CSS page, rather than just the one imported at the beginning of the `*.js` document.

For example, I have a `globalstyle.css` file that I am applying to almost every page using 
`import '../css/globalstyle.css'` on each page.

I have one page, however, that I don't want it on, but it applies the *css* from `globalstyle.css` anyway. I'm guessing that this is because `App.js` loads every page at once, but I don't know how to get around this.

```
class App extends Component { 


 render() {
    return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <HashRouter name="app" path="/" handler={App} basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>

     <SideNav/>
     <TopBar/>

      <Switch>
        <Route path = "/pages/dashboard.js" exact component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path = "/pages/home.js" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path = "/pages/tips.js" exact component={Tips} />
      </Switch>
      <Redirect from="/" exact to="/pages/home.js" />

    </HashRouter>

  </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

I don't want the globalstyle on the homepage.

Comment: Assuming this will all be done client side, a simple way would be to import those styles in the actual page components rather than on the root App one.

Comment: @Jayce444 yeah each of the imports for the stylesheets are only located on the individual pages, sorry if that wasn't clear!

Comment: If you don't want global styles on a particular page, then by definition they are not global.

Comment: @ksav yeah, I''m going to change it. It was used globally until I realized I needed a page that was completely different.

Comment: How different? You can override some of the css on this particular page using specificity. Or you can look into CSS in JS solutions to help you scope your CSS.

Comment: Also, you only need to import `globalstyle.css` once.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to get around this is to use css modules.CSS modules were introduced to solve this problem.

If you are using create-react-app to then it is supported out of the box. Refer here   https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/

If you want to set it up in a non create-react-app application then refer here  https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/css-modules-react/

Hope this helped.